# c# UWP Listview/Scrollviewer indicate more items

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

i have a Listview with big ListViewItems. I can show two items at the most and if the user wants to see more he has to scroll/swipe. However, this is a rare case.
The problem is, the user has no hint if there are more items and has to swipe for trial. I wonder if there is a best practice to indicate that there is more (hidden) content. My first simple approach would be a Textbox and show it if the ObservableCollection consists of more than two items but i doubt that this is the best way to do it.
What would be your approach?
Regards,
Nils

Comment: This question might have more attention on [User Experience Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) as here it might be flagged as _too broad_ and/or _primarly opinion-based_. Consider moving it there.

Comment: I will do so...as soon as i know how to move my question :-)

Comment: A moderator can do so, or you could simply copy-paste the question there, add a note that the question was migrated from Stack Overflow and delete the original one here.

Comment: For some apps, I switched the Auto flag for the VerticalScrollVisibility of the ListView to Visible, so that is will always be there hinting at the user there a more items. You need to add add the ListView template and change the Auto value to Visible ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299137.aspx )

Comment: I changed the VerticalScrollVisibility from Auto to Visible but i cannot see any difference. The scrollbar appears on "PointerOver" and disappears a few seconds after the pointer exits. Maybe i have to adjust some VisualStates too. Another problem is that most of our terminals run Windows10 in tablet mode, so there is no pointer.